# How to properly run methods after subscription data come?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like to find the best approach to running multiple methods, when some data arrives from Observable (e.g. HTTP request) and I need this data to call these methods.

I currently have 2 approaches, but both have some flaws in my opinion.

1. Call methods inside subscription:

```
  getSomeData(): void {
    this.httpService.getData.subscribe(data => {
        this.firstMethod(data);
        this.secondMethod(data.partOfData);
        this.thirdMethod();
    }
  }
```

I don't like this approach, because there is many lines of code when you need to call many methods. Of course I could wrap these 3 methods inside another function and call only that one function, but is this a good solution? I'm not sure...

2. Make request as Observable and subscribe to it seperately:

```
  getSomeData(): void {
    this.dataObservable = this.httpService.getData.pipe(share());
  }

  firstMethod() {
    dataObservable.subscribe(data => {...}
  }

  secondMethod() {
    dataObservable.subscribe(data => {...}
  }

  thirdMethod() {
    dataObservable.subscribe(data => {...}
  }
```

Here I'm not sure if subscribing multiple times to the same operator is a proper approach...

I would be very grateful for any recommendations / articles about this issue.

Comment: I honestly do not see a problem here, just a preference for how to structure your code and what you choose depends on bot the developer and the context of the code you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the first approach.  If you have to do 3 things then there is no way to avoid eventually writing 3 lines to do the 3 things.  Hiding it behind additional abstractions just turns your 3 things into 3*N things.

Look how much less code there is in your first method vs your second method.  Don't abstract until you have a need for an abstraction.  Your second method is preferable in situations where you need the flexibility of doing actions sometimes but not always.  By splitting up the actions into separate subscriptions, you have more control over which ones run when.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this issue! This is the most intuitive approach, but I thought it's not the best practice. Apparently I was wrong :)